# Do not reconnect the database for controler call

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo, silex

My controler call a method who is requested the database and return the result.

```
$connect = $this->connectBDD();

$rq = "SELECT naf, libelle FROM mytable WHERE naf ILIKE '$txt%'";
$t  = $connect->prepare($rq); $t->execute();
$t->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$tab = array();
while($top = $t->fetch()) {
    $tab[] = array(
        "text" => $top->naf . ": " . $top->libelle,
        "value" => $top->naf
    );
}

$t->closeCursor();

return $tab;
```

The problem comes from the first line $connect = $this->connectBDD(); who open the connexion. It takes times, ~ 1 seconde, and because this method is call very often (auto completion system), I need to memorize the connection to not reconnect at each call.

I try to memorize $connect in session

```
if( null === $this->app['session']->get('ac') ) {
    $this->app['session']->set('ac', $this->connectBDD() );
}

$connect = $this->app['session']->get('ac');


$rq = "SELECT naf, libelle FROM mytable WHERE naf ILIKE '$txt%'";
$t  = $connect->prepare($rq); $t->execute();
$t->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$tab = array();
while($top = $t->fetch()) {
    $tab[] = array(
        "text" => $top->naf . ": " . $top->libelle,
        "value" => $top->naf
    );
}

$t->closeCursor();

return $tab;
```

But it's worse, as if I have an infinite loop...

So, how can I call my method without reconnect the database at each call ?

Thanks for help

Comment: Why does it connect for a whole second? Is your database server is on the same computer? If so - did you try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: No it call a distinct server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make persistent connection in `connectBDD`

```
$dbh = new PDO('....', $user, $pass, array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: Yea well thought, it's better, my connection (the line $connect = $this->connectBDD();) takes ~0.33 seconde instead of 1 seconde to establish the connexion

Comment: But it seems not so quick for a persistent connection, no ?

Comment: @Macbernie it has nothing to do with persistent connection at all but with network latency which seems a huge one.